# Cocos2D iPhone - annoying black screens between CCTransitions

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a scene created like that:

**MyScene (subclass of CClayer)**

.m

```
+(CCScene *) sceneWithSprite:(CCSprite*)sback
{   
    return [[[self alloc] initWithSprite:sback] autorelease];
}

-(id) initWithSprite:(CCSprite*)sback
{    
    self = [super init];

      if (self) {

        self.spriteBack = sback;
        // sback is a sprite that comes from the previous scene

        // remove sback from that scene, so we can add it here
        [sback removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO];

        [self addChild:self.spriteBack z:-1];        

        CGSize windowSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        CGFloat midX = windowSize.width/2.0f;
        CGFloat midY = windowSize.height/2.0f;

        CCMenuItemLabel *menuItem1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"item 1" target:self selector:@selector(multi:)];
        CCMenuItemLabel *menuItem2 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"item 2" target:self selector:@selector(multi:)];
        CCMenuItemLabel *menuItem3 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"item 3" target:self selector:@selector(multi:)];

         CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuItem1, menuItem2, menuItem3, nil];
        [menu alignItemsVertically];
        [self addChild:menu];   

        menu.position = ccp(midX, midY);
  }
return self;
}
```

I need to do a fade down transition. I call the new scene, from the previous one, using

```
   CCScene *menu = [Menu sceneWithSprite:spriteBack];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: 
    [CCTransitionFadeDown transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:menu]];
```

The problem is that the transition happens to black then the new scene appears suddenly.

Is there a way to make the transition from the current scene to the new one without this black?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `CCTransitionCrossFade`.  If you have problems with that one fading to white in the middle of the crossfade, see this thread: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/28949

Comment: Thanks, that works, but this is a simple fade and my idea was to use that fade down effect, that is more interesting. No way to make it work, isn't it? Anyway, thanks.